# How to use setThreadPool() in Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I wanted to see how to use the `setThreadPool()` functionality. Let's say my main class is the following:

```
import javax.servlet.SingleThreadModel;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;

public class FServer implements SingleThreadModel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(x);

        server.setHandler(new Handler());


        server.start();
        server.join();


    }
}
```

When trying to add the `setThreadPool()`, I'm always asked to implement abstract methods.

My question is, how can I set the ThreadPool length for Jetty without being forced to use an XML configuration file, i.e. something like `server.setThreadPool(5)` where 5 is the number of simultaneous threads?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example:

```
QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
threadPool.setMaxThreads(5);
server.setThreadPool(threadPool);
```

Comment: Worked great for me to stop Jetty 6 from starting too many threads. I found this setting explained here http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Newbie+Guide+to+Jetty#NewbieGuidetoJetty-ThreadPooloptional. ExecutorThreadPool [as mentioned below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7454163/270662) seems to be available in Jetty 7+

Comment: Jetty 9 no longer has the server.setThreadPool() command. How do I set the thread pool now?

Comment: Now it can be set via constructor: `Server(@Name("threadpool") ThreadPool pool)`

Comment: Yeah, but how do you set that constructor param using the jetty.xml in Jetty 9?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following:

```
server.setThreadPool(new ExecutorThreadPool(5, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```