# How to increase Jetty threadpool size with jetty-runner on Heroku?

Tags: java, spring, heroku, jetty, threadpool

I have a Java (Spring MVC) webapp running on Heroku. It uses the setup described in this article:
[Getting Started with Spring MVC Hibernate on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/spring-mvc-hibernate)

It looks like Jetty by default uses just one thread. Given this Heroku & jetty-runner setup, **what is the simplest way to increase the threadpool size**?

NB: I do not have any custom Jetty related code (so it's unclear how I'd apply the advice e.g. at: [How to use setThreadPool() in Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444800/how-to-use-setthreadpool-in-jetty)). If possible, I'd prefer to keep it that way. Everything Jetty-related is now in Procfile and pom.xml (see below).

Can I set the threadpool size with some jetty-runner parameter or config option? If I need to create a Jetty config file, how do I make Heroku/jetty-runner use it?

Procfile:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                        <version>8.1.10.v20130312</version>
                        <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: (I've looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097557/how-to-multithread-jetty-restful-service-on-heroku?rq=1 but it just points to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444800/how-to-use-setthreadpool-in-jetty, which, as mentioned, doesn't directly answer my question.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What solved it for me (a Spring, not Jetty issue)

I was wrong when I wrote this in the question:

> It looks like Jetty by default uses just one thread.

This turned out to be purely a Spring issue. In applicationContext.xml, I changed

```
<task:annotation-driven/>
```

into

```
<task:annotation-driven scheduler="scheduler-pool"/>
<task:scheduler id="scheduler-pool" pool-size="5"/>
```

... and different `@Scheduled` tasks now happily run in separate threads like `scheduler-pool-1` or `scheduler-pool-3`.

### How to tweak Jetty threadpool configs (with jetty-runner)

<sup>(Before I realised my problem was *not* a Jetty issue, I had already looked into how Jetty threadpools are configured. Documenting that here; maybe it is useful to someone.)</sup>

Create a [`jetty.xml` config file](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty.xml) (somewhere like `src/main/resources` so that it gets copied to the compilation target dir), and customise it to your liking.

Example (probably a poor one):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For some reason, must use org.eclipse classes, 
 even though we depend on org.mortbay Jetty... -->

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <Set name="ThreadPool">
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
            <Set name="minThreads">3</Set>
            <Set name="maxThreads">5</Set>
        </New>
    </Set>

</Configure>
```

Then, tell jetty-runner to use that config file with the `--config` switch. So for example in Heroku's `Procfile`, add `--config target/classes/jetty.xml`:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --config target/classes/jetty.xml --port $PORT target/*.war
```

---

If you also happen to be using **jetty-maven-plugin**, you can tell it to use your custom Jetty config by adding this under `<configuration>` in `pom.xml`:

```
<jettyConfig>target/classes/jetty.xml</jettyConfig>
```

Comment: The default size of max connections in the thread pool is just 1?  Really?

Comment: @Luke, you can find default min/max threadpool size in /etc/jetty.xml relative to jetty directory. 10/200 are the default values